# Running PyQGIS standalone script on Ubuntu terminal (docker)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, docker

I am running a PyQGIS standalone script on Ubuntu terminal in a QGIS docker:

```
from qgis.core import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/qgis/installation", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
```

But I get the following error:

> QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to
>   '/tmp/runtime-root' qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect
>   to display Could not connect to any X display.

Answer (score 4):

The following solution worked for me:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -noreset & 
export DISPLAY=:99
instalacia xvfb:
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo apt-get install xvfb xserver-xephyr vnc4server
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

then in the code:

```
gui_flag = False
app = QgsApplication([b''], gui_flag)
app.setPrefixPath('/usr')
app.initQgis()
if len(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()) == 0:
    raise RuntimeError('No data providers available.')
```